# Deleted boot partiton

Tags: boot, live-cd, boot-partition

I only have ubuntu 16 installed and I have somewhere along the line of formatting external drives, formatted what i think is my boot partition. Now when I boot my laptop i just sent straight to bios.
I have tried boot-repair but to no avail and ran a smart(desktop utility) test and results can back as disk ok.
Anyone have any suggestion as to how to recover this so I can boot ubuntu again, without a complete reinstall?

Comment: is this an EFI system? can you post your partition list?

Comment: I dont have windows, just ubuntu so didn't think it would count as a duplicate!

Comment: @SimplySimplified don't let the title to mislead, the duplicate karel linked should work for your purposes.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thank you, I have had a read through, definitely helped. I have now managed to boot Ubuntu to the point of asking for my encryption pass phrase, but now it won’t take input from the keyboard!

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. It might help though if you ask a separate question about it, because it's already not quite about the deleted partition, and it would be weird if somebody under such question posted an answer about not working input from a keyboard. And btw, for posting the question it might also help to know where it asks for encryption phrase *(grub? lightdm? anywhere else?)* for those of us who might know the answer per se but didn't use encryption. You can also use a shot of your screen for this purpose.